# vagrant plugin install fails for any plugin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

Running `vagrant plugin install [plugin]` fails for any plugin (using an admin command prompt.) Not sure what the problem is. `dev/null` is not on my machine and it shouldn't be trying to install to a VM.

#### Tried:

- Uninstall Vagrant, delete `.vagrant.d` directory, reinstall Vagrant
- Update Vagrant's gems using its embedded Ruby
- Update VirtualBox
- Disable .bashrc file (tried it with Git Bash, too)

#### Using:

- Windows 7 Pro x64 SP1
- Vagrant 1.7.2
- VirtualBox 4.3.26

#### Output:

Note: `**` = `C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded`

```
C:\Users\Joe\Dropbox\webdev\projects>vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
Installing the 'vagrant-hostsupdater' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
**/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:554:in \`initialize': 
  Is a directory - /dev/null (Errno::EISDIR)
  from **/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:554:in \`open'
  from **/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:554:in \`initialize'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:283:in \`new'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:283:in \`with_isolated_gem'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:225:in \`internal_install'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:92:in \`install'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:62:in \`block in install_plugin'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in \`call'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in \`install_plugin'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:37:in \`call'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in \`call'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in \`call'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in \`block in run'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in \`busy'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in \`run'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:14:in \`action'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:32:in \`block in execute'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in \`each'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in \`execute'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in \`execute'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in \`execute'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:301:in \`cli'
  from **/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:174:in \`<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is a c:\dev\null directory (or maybe d:\dev\null etc).

initialize scripts looks for a /dev/null file but finds a directory. By deleting the directory everything works fine(it did to me)

Seems that some other linux ported application had created the c:\dev\null folder